# Unpublished Pages Failing To Appear On Custom Path

Tags: plugins, functions, theme-development, filters, hooks

### The Context

I have a domain, we'll call it *example.com*, where traffic travelling to this domain first hits a reverse proxy and depending on the path it is directed to two different containers.

Traffic going to the root path "/" is directed to a static Nuxt page. All other traffic "/*" is directed to the WordPress site.

The end result of this is we have a fast-loading landing page and the rest of the content is managed by WordPress.

We use **Elementor** for designing the WordPress pages.

### The Problem

Published pages, whether public or private, work fine as they appear under something other than the root path e.g. "*/somepage*". The issue arises with unpublished draft pages that try to use the root path and just append a query string e.g. "*/?page_id=1234*" - this obviously just redirects to the Nuxt site.

### Solution?

I'd think the easy solution would be just to have drafts appear on a custom path e.g. "*/draft?page_id=1234*". Following [this guide](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/php-wordpress-change-post-url-via-preview_post_link-filter/), I added some code to the *functions.php* theme file which uses the *preview_post_link* hook. Inspecting the preview links, it seems to have worked:

[image: prepended draft prefix]

The problem is when clicking the preview or even just visiting the URL with the *draft* prefix it just redirects back to the root path e.g. *example.com/draft/?page_id=1234&preview=true* **redirects to** *example.com/?page_id=1234*. This effectively is redirecting it back to the Nuxt site and fails to show the preview.

Considering this is on page load it must be some JS running on the page. Possibly this is Elementor overriding my custom functionality based on the permalinks but how do I stop this from happening and get it to work under my custom *draft* path?

For reference here is the snippet I added to the bottom of the *functions.php* file:

```php
function update_preview_link($link) {
    $parts = parse_url($link);
    $parts['path'] = "/draft" . $parts['path'];
    return $parts['scheme'] . "://" . $parts['host'] . $parts['path'] . (isset($parts['query']) ? "?" . $parts['query'] : "");
}
add_filter('preview_post_link', 'update_preview_link');
add_filter('preview_page_link', 'update_preview_link');
```

Comment: ***The solution here is to adjust your reverse proxy to also redirect `/?page_id=123` to WordPress, as well as any other URL that has GET parameters, this is not a WordPress or nuxt problem.*** If you do what you are trying to do in this question you will encounter this problem again but for searching ( `/?s=searchterm` ), and then again for other reasons. Changing the URLs WP uses is not the solution, and can cause compatibility problems with themes and plugins.

Comment: Using a subdirectory for WordPress would also solve this

Comment: Hmm ok. I've set a redirect for `/?page_id=.*`. *This does solve the specific issue I'm talking about here*. Doesn't feel right redirecting based on query params but I guess it's a non-standard setup anyway. The downside is I'll need to keep adding nginx rules every time I find something else on the root path.

Comment: The majority of the variables `WP_Query` takes as arguments are also valid URL parameters, not counting those that themes and plugins may add